# Entity Framework : joining dbcontext table with a List makes retrieval very slow slow

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

In my query  first I try to get only 500 market records everytime (PageSize=500). So next ideally i should be getting subsystems for only those 500 market records .   Thats why in 'subsytems' query I try to join with the filtered market record list . This query is extremely slow . Then I tried joining directly with dbContext.tblfitems in 'subsytems1' query . This query is faster than first one . But I am joining with all records in fitems ( marketrecords) . Ideally second one should be slow as join is with thousands of records but in earlier case its only 500 records . I just dont want to join with all records instead i just want to join 500 records . How do I proceed ?

```
List<MarketRecord> maketRecords = _dbContext.tblfitems.Where(x => x.MarketId == marketId)
                                                          .OrderBy(x => x.RecordId)
                                                          .Skip((pageIndex - 1) * PageSize)
                                                          .Take(PageSize)
                                                          .ToList();

    List<FSubsystem> subsytems = (from t1 in _dbContext.tblfsubsystems
                                     join t2 in maketRecords on t1.RecordId equals t2.RecordId
                                     where t2.MarketId == marketId
                                     select t1)
                                 .Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.RecordId).ThenBy(y => y.FSubsystemId).ToList();


    List<FSubsystem> subsytems1 = (from t1 in _dbContext.tblfsubsystems
                                  join t2 in _dbContext.tblfitems on t1.RecordId equals t2.RecordId
                                  where t2.MarketId == marketId
                                  select t1)
                                 .Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.RecordId).ThenBy(y => y.FSubsystemId).ToList();
```

Comment: Joining to an in-memory list makes the query drag the entire tblfsubsystems table into memory. Remove the `ToList` from the first query.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks David . works fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that joining an `IQueryable` to an in-memory list makes the query drag the entire `tblfsubsystems` table into memory, this is why your query is slow. The simple solution is not to materialise first list and keep that as an `IQueryable` too. So remove the `ToList` from the end, and use `var` to simplify the code, for example:

```
var maketRecords = _dbContext.tblfitems
    .Where(x => x.MarketId == marketId)
    .OrderBy(x => x.RecordId)
    .Skip((pageIndex - 1) * PageSize)
    .Take(PageSize);
```